# Android CollapsingToolbarLayout vertical positioning of children

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to setup a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with multiple view, but because `CollapsingToolbarLayout` extends `FrameLayout` I cant place view in the right order.

**This is what I am trying to achieve:**
**Expanded view:**

```
_____________________________
|Title toolbar               x|
|TextView A                   |
|TextView B                   |
|TextView C                   |
|SearchView                   |
|-----------------------------|
|RecyclerView content         |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|_____________________________|
```

**Collapsed View:**

```
 _____________________________
|Title toolbar               x|
|SearchView                   |
|-----------------------------|
|RecyclerView content         |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|...                          |
|_____________________________|
```

How do I place multiple views inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in vertical order (`TextView A`, `TextView B`, `TextView C`, `SearchView`), and set only the SearchView to be pinned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I place multiple views inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in
> vertical order (`TextView` A, `TextView` B, `TextView` C, `SearchView`)

You have to choose what you're good at it.

1. Using `LinearLayout` and the other widgets inside with [`android:orientation="vertical"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear).
2. Using `RelativeLayout` and [`android:layout_below`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams#attr_android:layout_below).
3. Using `ConstraintLayout` and constraints like [`layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout).

> set only the `SearchView` to be pinned?

Using `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` will help to pin the `SearchView` at the top while scrolling the content.

P.S: You may have to place it outside of the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`.